# allDocs query returning design docs in PouchDB

Tags: pouchdb

I'm using smart IDs in my docs so that I can search by log type and date. I am also using the pouchdb-find plugin to create indexes, though they aren't being used yet.

This is an example allDocs query:

```
var start = 'log_2015-05-28T23:00:00.000Z',
    end = 'log_2015-05-29T23:00:00.000Z;
return db.allDocs({ startKey: start, endKey: end, include_docs: true });
```

The results of this query includes design docs. Here's an example key of one of them:

_design/idx-a1f9f055e1ec4dfb9f5e9fd9ac7fc6bb

Why am I getting design docs back if their keys are outside of my start and end key range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `startkey` and `endkey`, not `startKey` and `endKey`. :)

Comment: doh! thanks! Sometimes I wish javascript was a typed language